# How to hide column with expression in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have to hide a column in a report depending on a parameter.
The Parameter (@vExclude) is a text type. It has the following available Options: the Label "None" with Value 0 or Label "Type1" with Value 1 or Label "Type2" with Label 2, it's possible to select multiple values, the default is 0.

The Column (SumCalc) i wanna hide is type money in SQL.

basically the logic is if @vExclude != "none", then show SumCalc in Report.
I've tried the following expressions:

```
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Label is ("none"), true, false)

=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Value is ("0"), true, false)

=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Value is ("0"), false, true)

=iif(InStr(Join(Parameters!vExclude.Label,","),"none")=0,true,false)
```

they all work without error, but do not hide the column correctly. Either SumCalc is always shown or never, but my condition never works.

Following expressions provided an error message:

```
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Label = ("none"), true, false) 
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Label = "none", true, false) 
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Value = 0, true, false) 
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Value is 0, true, false) 
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Value = "0", true, false) 
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Value = ("0"), true, false) 
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Value = (0), true, false) 
=iif(Parameters!vExclude.Value is (0), true, false)
```

Does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong in my expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. Note that we have used the Value as we are checking for umbers here.

```
=Join(Parameters!vExclude.Value,",").Contains(0)=False
```

This basically reads "If vExclude does not contain 0" which will return `True` of it does not contain zero or `False` if it does contain 0. No need to use an `IIF()`, just use this as the expression for the `Hidden` property.

Comment: you might need to change your parameter type to numeric for hits to work - not sure without testing

Comment: no need to change the parameter, only need to turn around the statement to =Join(Parameters!vExclude.Value,",").Contains(0)=True, Thank you!